# How to use PowerShell to refresh a dev database from backup of prod

Tags: powershell

We are using DDBoost to backup and restore SQL Server databases.

Now we want to create a script or a job, so developers can kick off the script or the job to refresh their dev databases without asking a DBA.

I know in SQL Server Management Studio we can't take input in Job so I want to create a script with T-SQL or CLI or Powershell to take inputs like SourceDB, TargetDB, and then refresh a dev database using with the parameters.

I know how to take input in PowerShell so if someone can tell how to do it either by:

- Using powershell to restore from DDBoost
- Passing the values from PowerShell to T-SQL or CLI
- Any other option in SQL Server management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore the fact about DDBoost, because I don't know it.

But I know about [dbatools.io](https://dbatools.io), which is very solid powershell module that does exactly what you are looking for. It can with one line of powershell restore an entire database. You can make it as simple or advanced as you want.

Prerequisites:

1. A working SQL Server backup file. This can be created from SQL
   Server Management Studio or dbatools.io
2. A SQL Server
3. The executing user needs privileges to restore the database.
4. Install dbatools

**Installation**

Start PowerShell (Run As Administrator)

```
Install-Module dbatools
```

**Backup database**

Here I'll show how you can backup a database using dbatools.

```
Backup-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance servername -Database databasename -BackupDirectory C:\Temp -CompressBackup
```

**Restore database**

Here I'll show how you can restore a database using dbatools.

```
Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance servername -DatabaseName databasename -Path C:\Temp\filename.bak -WithReplace -useDestinationDefaultDirectories -ReplaceDbNameInFile
```

The restore script instructs the SQL Server to overwrite any existing database. It will restore the database files into the folders that are configured inside the SQL Server configuration and it will replace the database name in the physical files.

Comment: Hi Motz,  Excellent, Thanks for the quick reply.  However, our backups are stored in a storage like SAN (which is being accessed by DDBOOST (a tool) so I have to pull down backup file from there, here is a sample script if I restore from DDBoost tool:

Comment: EXEC   @returnCode = dbo.emc_run_restore ' 
-a DD_HOST=pezdd01       (It is where our databases' backups are stored like SAN) 
-a DD_USER=DDboost               (this is ddboost user which has access to the backups) 
-a DEVICE_PATH=/SQLBoost_UGL     (path of the storage)
-a "DD_LOCKBOX_PATH=C:\common\lockbox"   
-c ProdSRV                    (Source (Prod DB) server )
-A DevSRV      (Target (Dev DB) server )
-a "SKIP_CLIENT_RESOLUTION=TRUE" 
-C "''ess_ug''=''I:\mssql\DATA\TargetDB.mdf'', ''ess_ug_log''=''J:\mssql\Log\TargetDB_LOG.ldf''" 
-f -S normal -d MSSQL:TargetDB MSSQL:SOURCEDB'

Comment: Please update your question to contain the sample script. If you have a sample script, have you even tried to make it into a PowerShell script?

Comment: Hi Motz, Actually the above para is taken from a job which could refresh a dev database from backup of production DB.

There is no option to take input from users like which DB they want to refresh i.e. TargetDB and SourceDB etc. in Script or Job in SQL Server Management Studio.

So my intention to take input in PS and then pass the values to T-SQL or CLI then integrate into the job, so a user would run the script or click the job to run manually. If you have any hint to take input in job or script then would be great.

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks.

Shoaib